# WeatherLib -- Volley.jar error causing app to crash

Tags: java, android, debugging, jar, android-volley

I am trying to implement a weather app using - https://github.com/survivingwithandroid/WeatherLib/tree/master/demo

However I am getting the following error after cleaning, rebuilding, restarting etc. --

```
09-22 14:35:26.519    8083-8083/com.the.app.the E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest', referenced from method com.survivingwithandroid.weather.lib.client.volley.WeatherClientDefault._doSearch
09-22 14:35:26.519    8083-8083/com.the.app.the E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest', referenced from method com.survivingwithandroid.weather.lib.client.volley.WeatherClientDefault.getCurrentCondition
09-22 14:35:26.519    8083-8083/com.the.app.the E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageRequest', referenced from method com.survivingwithandroid.weather.lib.client.volley.WeatherClientDefault.getDefaultProviderImage
09-22 14:35:26.519    8083-8083/com.the.app.the E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest', referenced from method com.survivingwithandroid.weather.lib.client.volley.WeatherClientDefault.getForecastWeather
09-22 14:35:26.519    8083-8083/com.the.app.the E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest', referenced from method com.survivingwithandroid.weather.lib.client.volley.WeatherClientDefault.getHistoricalWeather
09-22 14:35:26.519    8083-8083/com.the.app.the E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest', referenced from method com.survivingwithandroid.weather.lib.client.volley.WeatherClientDefault.getHourForecastWeather
09-22 14:35:26.519    8083-8083/com.the.app.the E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageRequest', referenced from method com.survivingwithandroid.weather.lib.client.volley.WeatherClientDefault.getImage
09-22 14:35:26.519    8083-8083/com.the.app.the E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest', referenced from method com.survivingwithandroid.weather.lib.client.volley.WeatherClientDefault.getProviderWeatherFeature
09-22 14:35:26.519    8083-8083/com.the.app.the E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageRequest', referenced from method com.survivingwithandroid.weather.lib.client.volley.WeatherClientDefault.getWeatherImage
09-22 14:35:26.529    8083-8083/com.the.app.the E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest', referenced from method com.survivingwithandroid.weather.lib.client.volley.WeatherClientDefault.searchCityByLocation
09-22 14:35:26.629    8083-8083/com.the.app.the E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
            at com.survivingwithandroid.weather.lib.client.volley.WeatherClientDefault.init(WeatherClientDefault.java:95)
            at com.survivingwithandroid.weather.lib.WeatherClient$ClientBuilder.build(WeatherClient.java:482)
            at com.the.app.the.Weather.WeatherContext.getClient(WeatherContext.java:38)
            at com.the.app.the.Weather.fragment.WeatherFragment.onActivityCreated(WeatherFragment.java:47)
            at com.the.app.the.Weather.fragment.CurrentWeatherFragment.onActivityCreated(CurrentWeatherFragment.java:75)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:848)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5211)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2108)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1204)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4941)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:561)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Im still fairly new to app dev, so Im unsure where the error lies. i know it has something to do with the volley.jar, i've added my jars to lib and added them as library as well. When clicking the files that are in the library it tells me Sources not found, I try attaching sources but it does nothing.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

***UPDATE***
Ok so it seems that I was missing a library, thanks to @Francesco for pointing that out. However after adding the library, the current weather tab seems to show fine but when clicking on the forecast tab, I know receive this error ---

```
09-23 11:39:52.354  18832-18832/com.thewave.app.thewave E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.survivingwithandroid.weather.lib.R$string
            at com.survivingwithandroid.weather.lib.WeatherCode.<clinit>(WeatherCode.java:36)
            at com.survivingwithandroid.weather.lib.provider.openweathermap.OpenweathermapCodeProvider.getWeatherCode(OpenweathermapCodeProvider.java:98)
            at com.survivingwithandroid.weather.lib.provider.openweathermap.OpenweathermapProvider.getForecastWeather(OpenweathermapProvider.java:251)
            at com.survivingwithandroid.weather.lib.client.volley.WeatherClientDefault$9.onResponse(WeatherClientDefault.java:454)
            at com.survivingwithandroid.weather.lib.client.volley.WeatherClientDefault$9.onResponse(WeatherClientDefault.java:449)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
            at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4941)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:561)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can explain:"i've added my jars to lib and added them as library as well" further and also whats your IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the dev behind the lib you are using.
I guess you didn't referenced correctly the library.
If you are using Android studio i suggest to you to add the dependency in your graddle file

```
dependencies {                  
compile 'com.survivingwithandroid:weatherlib:1.5.2'
compile 'com.survivingwithandroid:weatherlib_volleyclient:1.5.2'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.6@aar' (or whatever you like)
```

}

otherwise if you use eclipse you can clone the volley project and add it as project dependency. 
If you want to have more info give a look here:
[Weatherlib](http://survivingwithandroid.github.io/WeatherLib/)

Comment: thanks! I updated my question cause now Im getting another error which seems to be from the libs.

Comment: What language are you using? It seems it can't load the weather description. Can you extract the weather code?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean. Im using english, and Im working in Android Studio IDE. How can I extract the weather code?

Comment: Did you give a look at the demo (https://github.com/survivingwithandroid/WeatherLib/tree/dev/demo15)